# Ionic3: loading some code at app start?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In an ionic 3.9.2 app, I was using `AppComponent` to load some code (this code requests a back-end to set some global variables for the whole ionic app). It worked well.

However, now, I'm using deeplinks.
Now, each time a user access a specific page app via the URL, these global variables are not set (app component is not called) and I got errors.

I can not use `ngOnInit()` because it would call the requests for every page. I really need this code to be called once at app startup, but no matter which page is requested by the user.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write your own init function in a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), and call it in every page that you need. Your service will look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
static alreadyInitialized = false;
export class MyserviceService {
   constructor() { }


    initialize(){
       if (this.alreadyInitialized){
          return
       }
        this.alreadyInitialized  = true;

       //Do you initialization here...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was considering using something similar, but was feeling it should exist a better solution, that does not force you to make the same call in ALL your pages.